# Contenttools - appending data via jQuery

Tags: javascript

For reasons relative to MathJax, I need to dynamically clear content from a Contenttools editable region, and then append new elements to the editable region. When I append elements to the region, they are not seen as editable by Contenttools. I'm using the following jQuery code in an AJAX callback:

```
$(".contentArea").empty().append($(response.data.content))
```

The content appears as I want it, but isn't editable. Can anyone help me? I've also tried re-init'ing the editor using editor.init(...) after the new content is loaded, but that didn't seem to register the new content either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Couple of quick questions: Is the CT editor active (e.g are you editing) when you try to replace the contents of the region? Is the content you are inserting formatted by MathJax before being inserted or before you try to initialize the editor again?

Comment: @AnthonyBlackshaw When MathJax gets rendered, it transforms the TeX to MathML. I don't want to edit the MathML markup, but rather the TeX (like $x^2+7$ within the innerHTML of an element). 

I'm trying to do the following: when the editor starts, reload the page content  into the page (as to remove the MathML markup, returning it to the TeX markup), then start editing that content. Therefore I'm trying to replace the content when the editor starts (I'm binding this to the 'start' event of editor._ignition). I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi @Grant Sanders - I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it sounds like what's happening is that when you request your Tex version of the content to replace the current MathML the editor is started and so when you replace the content within the editable region it's live causing the editor and the page to become out of sync.

I can't try this out easily for your exact scenario but the following code outlines the initial approach I would take to solve what you've described, if you let me know how you get on and if any revisions are required I'll happily update it.

```
var editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();

// Add a flag to the editor that indicates when the tex version of the content
// has loaded.
editor.texLoaded = false;

// Capture the start event against the editor, the first time around we load
// the tex version of our content, the second time around we intialize the 
// editor as normal. 
editor.addEventListener('start', function(ev) {

    // Has the Tex content been loaded, if so do nothing we're ready to start
    // editing.
    if (this.texLoaded) {
        return;
    }

    // If the Tex content hasn't been loaded then cancel the start event
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Load the Tex content
    $.ajax({
        url: "/get-tex?..."
    }).done(function (response) {
        // From the response update the contents of the editable region
        $('.contentArea')[0].innerHTML = response.data.content;

        // Flag that the tex version of the content is now in place
        this.texLoaded = true;

        // Start the editor
        editor.start();
    });
});
```

Comment: This works! I just had to toggle the value of this.texLoaded in the 'stop' and 'save' event listeners so that subsequent edits have the same functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the content is being loaded but you can not edit?
Try this way

```
$(".contentArea").empty().append($(response.data.content));
//Reset the editable function
```